# Spring Boot - BigInteger value in the response body is not correct

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, biginteger

I have a field "old" with the data type BigInteger in Spring Boot.

Property in Entity:

```
@Column(name = "old")
private java.math.BigInteger old;
```

In the database, this field "old" is of the following data type: Number(20,0).

Column in Oracle Database:

```
old NUMBER(20,0)
```

When reading the entity, I get the following value: 12345678912345678912 from the database. (I can see this in Debugger.) This is correct. The same value is in the database.

However, I get the following value in the response body: 12345678912345680000. This is not correct.

Response as JSON

```
{
...
"old": 12345678912345680000,
...
}
```

How can I get the correct value in the response body?

Comment: I can't reproduce your case. With Spring Boot 3.2.3 getting correct JSON `"old": 12345678912345678912`

Comment: It seems to be a client problem with bruno-API-Client. With Postman I get the correct value.